# How can I get the frame of a UIView subclass using Autolayout with Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

When I use a subclass of `UIView` and put it on the storyboard with some constraints,i check its frame in `awakeFromNib()` or `didMoveToWindow()`. The result is not correct cause the constraints are not applied yet.

Is there any callback to inform me that the constraints are applied? So after that i can do sth with the correct frame.

Comment: You mean, like, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `awakeFromNib` `viewDidLoad` or `didMoveToWindow` is called, layout is not completed yet. You have to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`of a viewController. This method will be called after applying constraints and completing layout.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: that works. But this function is in `UIViewController`. So i still need to execute function of `UIView` here manually. I mean, can my UIView get the callback (when its layout is finished) with some built-in method?

Comment: You mean, like `layoutSubviews`?